# Quickly select all elements with css background image

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I want to grab all elements on a page that have a css background-image. I can do this via a filter function, but it's very slow on a page with many elements:

```
$('*').filter(function() {
    return ( $(this).css('background-image') !== '' );
}).addClass('bg_found');
```

Is there any faster way to select elements with background images?

Comment: This code is working? but just slow?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If there are any tags that you know will not have a background image, you can improve the selection be excluding those with the [`not-selector`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/).

```
$('*:not(span,p)')
```

Aside from that, you could try using a more native API approach in the filter.

```
$('*').filter(function() {
    if (this.currentStyle) 
              return this.currentStyle['backgroundImage'] !== 'none';
    else if (window.getComputedStyle)
              return document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(this,null)
                             .getPropertyValue('background-image') !== 'none';
}).addClass('bg_found');
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/q63eU/

The code in the filter is based on the getStyle code from: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html

---

*Posting a `for` statement version to avoid the function calls in `.filter()`.*

```
var tags = document.getElementsByTagName('*'),
    el;

for (var i = 0, len = tags.length; i < len; i++) {
    el = tags[i];
    if (el.currentStyle) {
        if( el.currentStyle['backgroundImage'] !== 'none' ) 
            el.className += ' bg_found';
    }
    else if (window.getComputedStyle) {
        if( document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue('background-image') !== 'none' ) 
            el.className += ' bg_found';
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 The undocumented function `$.css` may be useful here, but I don't know what its performance would be compared to the code you suggest.

Comment: You can get an additional (if small) performance boost by moving the `currentStyle` / `getComputedStyle` test out of the filter function: `$("*").filter(window.getComputedStyle ? function() { return "none" === window.getComputedStyle(this, null).backgroundImage } : function() { return "none" === this.currentStyle.backgroundImage }).addClass('bg_found');` (Does anyone else **really wish** we could create multiline comments?)

Comment: This is indeed faster, mostly because of comparing the background-image style against 'none' instead of ''.  On a large page my time was cut down from over 14 seconds to just about 4.

Comment: @lonesomeday: I think you're right that it would have shown a good improvement over `$(this).css()`.

Comment: @Ben Blank - I'm not sure exactly why, but your modified solution runs nearly as slowly as the original. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @Jeremy — Well, it was a nice theory.  ;-)

Comment: @Jeremy: [Try this.](http://jsfiddle.net/q63eU/2/) It is the concept @Ben was using, but with a couple tweaks.

Comment: ...ultimately the fastest will be to ditch the `.filter()` altogether and use a `for` loop. http://jsfiddle.net/q63eU/3/