# getComputedStyle() and properties that can have a url associated with them

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to make a snippet of javascript that can get a list of all images (or other resources) that are used in a web page because they are referenced in the css.  Typically they are background images, because somewhere in the css there is something like this:

```
.something {
  background: transparent url(images/somethingbg.png) no-repeat top left;
  }
```

It seems I can get all of these into an array (with their full path) with the following snippet:

```
var outputArray = [];
var string = "";
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
for (var i = 0; i<elems.length; i++) {
 var elem = elems[i];
 var style = window.getComputedStyle(elem, null);
 var value = style.getPropertyValue("background-image");
 if (value && value != "" && value != "none")
  outputArray.push(value);
 }
```

However, I want this to work on any file out there (running as a bookmarklet), and I know url() can apply to things that aren't background images, for instance "list-style-image".  Are there more?  Is there a list of these somewhere?

Comment: Are you asking "What are all the possible values that can be used in in url() that are not background images?" ?

Comment: @jessegavin, i think he is asking for all the properties that can validly accept `url(..)` as a value..

Comment: @jessegavin  Yes, that's what I'm asking. But keep in mind that I am using getComputedStyle(), so if you use something like "background" in the css and have a url in there, all my code needs to know about is "background-image".

Comment: possible duplicate of [List of All Background Images in DOM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430503/list-of-all-background-images-in-dom)

Comment: @jessegavin : actually, although I hadn't seen that question you refer to, the snippet of code in my question above answers that question pretty well.  However, it doesn't answer my own question. :)

Comment: @rob, you're right. I am sorry. I can't un-close. I feel bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK here's a pretty exhaustive (?) list:

1. background-image (shorthand
   background) beware of multiple
   `url("")` in CSS3
2. list-style-image (shorthand
   list-style)
3. behavior (-ms-behavior), [filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530752%28VS.85%29.aspx) (-ms-filter), [filter](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html#FilterProperty) and -moz-binding
4. cursor
5. content
6. attribute selectors which contain URI
   values: href, cite, xmlns, src,
   data-*, data, codebase, classid, archive, longdesc, profile…
7. @import, @namespace and @font-face